# Comparing acidity between groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

> [image]

I tried to do this using the stability of conjugate base. I can see (2) will be most stable due to resonance however my confusion lies in (1) and (3).
While in (3), the negative charge is unstable but in (1) I can't tell if it will take part in resonance because in pyridine the lone pair doesn't take part in resonance so is the same thing happening here?

Comment: Pretty much. If 1 is deprotonated, the resulting lone pair is perpendicular to the pi system of the ring, therefore only indirectly resonance stabilised (i.e. the ionic configuration would contribute more). This position should be a bit more acidic, because nitrogen is a bit more electronegative than carbon.

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be A.

Since 3 is vinylic hydrogen, therefore it is least acidic.
Both 1 and 2 are allylic and are at the alpha position with respect to the carbonyl group. 
Nitrogen is quite electronegative, therefore hydrogen 1 is more acidic than hydrogen 2. Hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer - A**

**Explanation -**

3 is least acidic as the negative charge developed after removal of hydrogen atom will not take part in resonance like other acidic hydrogens marked.

Both 1 and 2 will be resonance stabilized after removal of acidic H+ but 1 is more stable than 2 because the negative charge developed will be on Nitrogen atom which is more electronegative as compared to carbon. More electronegative atom would like to have electrons to complete its octet.

**So, the order will be 1>2>3**